# ui-sref activates all the ui-views within ng-repeat, how to target a specific ui-view in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

> I am new to AngularJS

I have a screen where i need to display multiple contents (from partial) dynamically by iterating an array. That content should be displayed up on clicking the corresponding link. I am using a ui-view which is repeated using ng-repeat also i have ui-sref initialized, but i am not able to target ui-sref to a specific ui-view.

```
link1 (ui-sref=link)
  content1 (ui-view=content)
link2 (ui-sref=link)
  content2 (ui-view=content)
link3 (ui-sref=link)
  content3 (ui-view=content)
```

here is the sample of what i am trying to do.
http://plnkr.co/edit/zFfbTD?p=preview

How do i target a ui-sref to a ui-view. these contents are dynamic.

Any help is well appreciated!

Thanks!
Raj.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: even now i use named views, the problem with the named views are the events (ui-sref) are listened by listeners of multiple views with the same name (in my case). I am looking for something like where i can dynamically add id to the ui-view so i can pair ui-sref with the ui-view? any suggestions?

Comment: You can't have multiple named views of the same name

Comment: ah.. is there any work around to it or best practice to it?

Comment: Use different view names

Comment: :) i love to, but the thing is the data is dynamic so i dont know how many views it would take to render the list of content. thats why i am looking for an alternative

Comment: i got it figured it out... ng-include is my saviour :+1:

Answer (score 2):

i found a way to this problem.

`ng-include`

check this out: http://plnkr.co/edit/zFfbTD?p=preview